# Pytorch CrossEntropyLoss from single dimensional Tensors

Tags: python, pytorch

I am missing something here: why does `CrossEntropyLoss` not work with single dimensional Tensors?

```
from  torch  import Tensor                                                                                                                                     
X =Tensor([1.0,2.0,3.0])                                                                                                                                       
labs = Tensor([2,2,3])                                                                                                                                         
loss = nn.CrossEntropyLoss().forward(X,labs)
```

```
_stacklevel, dtype)
   1315         dim = _get_softmax_dim('log_softmax', input.dim(), _stacklevel)
   1316     if dtype is None:
-> 1317         ret = input.log_softmax(dim)
   1318     else:
   1319         ret = input.log_softmax(dim, dtype=dtype)

IndexError: Dimension out of range (expected to be in range of [-1, 0], but got 1)
```

Why does that fail and what should be changed to get the desired result?

Comment: CrossEntropyLoss expects the input to be in the form of  `(minibatch,C)` or `(minibatch, C, d_1, d_2, ..., d_K)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you see the documentation [here](http://pytorch.org/docs/0.3.0/nn.html?highlight=crossentropyloss#torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss/)!

```
Input: (N,C) where C = number of classes
Target: (N) where each value is 0 <= targets[i] <= C-1
Output: scalar. If reduce is False, then (N) instead.
```

So it expects the input as 2D tensor
and target as 1D

```
import torch
from  torch  import Tensor                                                                                                                                 
X =Tensor([[1.0,2.0,3.0]])   #2D                                                                                                                                   
labs = torch.LongTensor([2]) # 0 <= targets[i] <= C-1                                                                                                                          
loss = nn.CrossEntropyLoss().forward(X,labs)
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is discussed in the pytorch forums [here](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/looking-for-a-cross-entropy-loss-that-accepts-two-tensors-of-the-same-shape/61302). As Prajot pointed out correctly, generally it does not make sense for a single input sample to have three different labels, so only a single label per input is accepted. The post on the forums discusses workarounds for advanced use cases where it might make sense.